# Struggling trying to get cookie out of response with HttpClient in .net 4.5

Tags: c#, async-await, dotnet-httpclient

I've got the following code that works successfully.  I can't figure out how to get the cookie out of the response.  My goal is that I want to be able to set cookies in the request and get cookies out of the response.  Thoughts?

```csharp
private async Task<string> Login(string username, string password)
{
    try
    {
        string url = "http://app.agelessemail.com/account/login/";
        Uri address = new Uri(url);
        var postData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", username),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password ", password)
        };

        HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData);
        var cookieJar = new CookieContainer();
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler
        {
            CookieContainer = cookieJar,
            UseCookies = true,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false
        };

        var client = new HttpClient(handler)
        {
            BaseAddress = address
        };


        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url,content);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        string body = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return body;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return e.ToString();
    }
}
```

Here is the complete answer:

```csharp
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url,content);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

Uri uri = new Uri(UrlBase);
var responseCookies = cookieJar.GetCookies(uri);
foreach (Cookie cookie in responseCookies)
{
    string cookieName = cookie.Name;
    string cookieValue = cookie.Value;
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, can I ask why you want to read cookies on the client?  My understanding is that cookies are used for sending information to the server, not for returning information.

Comment: I use the returned cookie on calls that return JSON so that I don't have to do a separate authorization call for each JSON call.  That is to say, I have a call log /Home/GetData which returns JSON but only if authorized.  On the client request, I add the cookie so that /Home/GetData will respond. Otherwise it will say "403" unauthorized.

Comment: Setting the authorization header as a default header is almost as effective and a bit more standard.  There is just no way for the server to set the auth header automatically on behalf of the client.

Comment: thanks for the tip Darrel. Do you have any examples of what that might look like in asp.net?  I struggled with this for my monotouch and now my windows store app. I'd be happy if there was a simple way.  This is a pain, especially with async and await now on windows store apps.

Answer (score 222, accepted):

To add cookies to a request, populate the cookie container before the request with `CookieContainer.Add(uri, cookie)`. After the request is made the cookie container will automatically be populated with all the cookies from the response. You can then call GetCookies() to retreive them.

```
CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.CookieContainer = cookies;

HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("http://google.com").Result;

Uri uri = new Uri("http://google.com");
IEnumerable<Cookie> responseCookies = cookies.GetCookies(uri).Cast<Cookie>();
foreach (Cookie cookie in responseCookies)
    Console.WriteLine(cookie.Name + ": " + cookie.Value);

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Note:  After receiving the initial cookies in the first call, when accessing any pages from the same domain, the cookies will be sent automatically, no additional steps needed.

Comment: You must add "using System.linq;"

Comment: ^^ System.Linq is only required if you wish to utilize the .Cast<> method, it's not required for the cookie retrieval, but this should be self explanatory :)

Comment: Is it possible to get cookies the same way if `httpclient` is built from the httpclient factory ?

i.e builder method added to services.AddHttpClient

Comment: on get Async we already made a reference to "google.com", why do we need to declare a URI with a reference to it again?

Comment: very nice solution and works well for the scenario where serverside is making a request that has a Set-Cookies header in response

Comment: @MikeDub Why would we use the cast in the first place if it is already in the correct form?

Comment: @FireController1847 you only need to cast if you want to use it as a IEnumerable<Cookie>, as the GetCookies() method returns a CookieCollection, not IEnumerable<Cookie>. IMO the cast is not required if all you are doing is using the loop in the code above as you can still Enumerate over a CookieCollection due to it inheriting IEnumerable.

Comment: This solution works in .net core as well.  Thanks!

Answer (score 24):

There's alternative if you don't have access to the `HttpClient` and can't inject the `CookieContainer`. This works in .NET Core 2.2:

```
private string GetCookie(HttpResponseMessage message)
{
    message.Headers.TryGetValues("Set-Cookie", out var setCookie);
    var setCookieString = setCookie.Single();
    var cookieTokens = setCookieString.Split(';');
    var firstCookie = cookieTokens.FirstOrDefault();
    var keyValueTokens = firstCookie.Split('=');
    var valueString = keyValueTokens[1];
    var cookieValue = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(valueString);
    return cookieValue;
}
```

Comment: Just tried this, the `var setCookieString = setCookie.Single();`  should probably be changed as it is quite possible for `setCookie` to have multiple values and thus cause an exception to be thrown. I ended up adding a parameter `string cookieName` and then used `setCookie.Single(x => x.StartsWith(cookieName));`. This does still assume the requested cookie exists.

Comment: `Set-Cookie` header does have multiple values, they are separated by a semicolon(`;`), but normally there should be only a single `Set-Cookie` header

Answer (score 8):

You can easily get a cookie value with the given URL.

```
private async Task<string> GetCookieValue(string url, string cookieName)
{
    var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    var uri = new Uri(url);
    using (var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
    {
        CookieContainer = cookieContainer
    })
    {
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler))
        {
            await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
            var cookie = cookieContainer.GetCookies(uri).Cast<Cookie>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == cookieName);
            return cookie?.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Not in every case you can add `httpClientHandler` to `httpClient`. For example, when you use integration tests `testServer.CreateClient()` or inject `httpClient` from `IHttpClientFactory`. So, I have simply read values from header.

```
    public static List<Cookie> GetCookies(this HttpResponseMessage message)
    {
        message.Headers.TryGetValues("Set-Cookie", out var cookiesHeader);
        var cookies = cookiesHeader.Select(cookieString => CreateCookie(cookieString)).ToList();
        return cookies;
    }

    private static Cookie CreateCookie(string cookieString)
    {
        var properties = cookieString.Split(';', StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries);
        var name = properties[0].Split("=")[0];
        var value = properties[0].Split("=")[1];
        var path = properties[2].Replace("path=", "");
        var cookie = new Cookie(name, value, path)
        {
            Secure = properties.Contains("secure"),
            HttpOnly = properties.Contains("httponly"),
            Expires = DateTime.Parse(properties[1].Replace("expires=", ""))
        };
        return cookie;
    }
```

`CreateCookie` method may be modified to exactly match your cookie properties.