# How to implement it via iFrame?

Tags: html, authentication, web, iframe

I have a situation, when I should to send a POST request to authenticate user, if it's succeed then server set a cookie and then we can get a protected page:

1. First request by Postman:

[image]

2. Second request (after first):

[image]

I need to implement it on web page. As I understand now, it's possible only via frames. How to do it? First request should be sent automatically after opening a page, so, user should open the page and see a protected page.

Comment: What is your question and what is the problem?

Comment: I need to ask some questions:                                                                                              1.In case of first when u send POST request .How will u be taking user credentials  to authenticate? 2. If he got authenticated successfully then only protected page should be visible ,Till this process will loading bar display in web page?

Comment: I'm not sure of understanding well your question. Why can't you just get the cookie and redirect the user to the protected page?

Comment: I think ajax will solve your problem. See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870371/why-is-jquerys-ajax-method-not-sending-my-session-cookie

Answer (score -1):

Cookie Authentication is you are trying to achieve?, here is are some links which will help to you with that. 
https://dzone.com/articles/cookie-authentication-with-aspnet-core-20