# Issue while returning cookie from .net core 3.1 application running in kubernetes

Tags: asp.net-core, kubernetes, asp.net-core-3.1, kubernetes-pod

I have an application A that add response cookies for the domain "abc.com" when I access this application over ingress via browser, e.g `https://my-application-myingress.abc.com`, cookies are perfectly returned.

But when the same call is done by .net core Application B using `httpclient` from another Pod using svc URL `"https://my-application"` no cookie is returned.

I suspected because the domain is not mentioned that's the reason. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: How exactly is your cluster configured? What's the version of Kubernetes, is it cloud/bare-metal?

Answer (score 0):

Your application A is `https://my-application-myingress.abc.com`, when you access the site and you can get cookie by broswer.

When your application B access the application A's svc url by HttpClient, then your application B server should be the `Client`, I mean you can [check the cookie value in your HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13318204/7687666). I know you maybe check the cookie in your broswer, you can't see cookies like browsers accessing application A directly.This is expected behavior.

If you want to get a special value in cookie, it is recommended to return the Cookie in HttpClient as a parameter to your Application B. I think this can be used as an alternative.